# Не могу подключить библиотеку jNetPcap на Android Studio

Tags: java, android, jnetpcap

Собственно пытаюсь подключить библиотеку чтобы запустить примеры. Вот из-за этой библиотеки не работает Core Protocol Pack (https://github.com/slytechs-repos/protocol-pack-api). Вот ошибка:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"com.android.tools.r8.internal.L10: Type sort is not supported: 9","sources":[{"file":"D:\\AndroidStudioProjects\\UbInf\\app\\libs\\core-protocols-0.9-SNAPSHOT.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"com.android.tools.r8.internal.L10: Type sort is not supported: 9","sources":[{"file":"D:\\AndroidStudioProjects\\UbInf\\app\\libs\\core-protocols-0.9.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}

> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexFileDependenciesTask$DexFileDependenciesWorkerAction
      > Error while dexing.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexFileDependenciesTask$DexFileDependenciesWorkerAction
      > Error while dexing.
```

И вот еще, если кто то будет смотреть

```
   * Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at 
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.tryTransition(StateTransitionController.java:177)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.executeTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:255)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkGraphController$DefaultBuildWorkGraph.runWork(DefaultBuildWorkGraphController.java:220)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.doRun(DefaultBuildController.java:181)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.access$000(DefaultBuildController.java:50)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController$BuildOpRunnable.run(DefaultBuildController.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$MultipleTaskActionFailures: Multiple task action failures occurred:
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:271)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:233)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:216)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:199)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100)
        at 

... 35 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.r8.internal.vc: Could not parse code
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:136)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:157)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:1)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.r8.internal.vc: Could not parse code
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:588)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:547)
    ... 43 more
    Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.internal.vc: Could not parse code
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.k4.G0(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:21)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:138)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:139)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:137)
```

Возможно более старая версия может помочь, но я не знаю там ее нету.

Comment: Нельзя же так просто тянуть все что под руку попадется в Андроид проект. Где автор библиотеки упомянул что она работает на Андроиде? Вот вам D8 и пишет, что не может это "переварить" в DEX-байткод.